# How to import "price per customer" csv file from /var/import/price/ folder to Magento 2.4.1 automatically?

Tags: magento2, php, import

I'm new in Magento 2 and have not enough experience in coding, I need help to import the Price per customer CSV file into Magento 2.4.1 version automatically. I use the Price Per Customer extension in Magento that provides an option to import manually. But our Navision system generates price files in /var/import/price dir. every 5 minutes, so we require to import these files to Magento 2 through extension auto and then remove imported files from dir. I need your help if anyone knows how to do this. Thank You for your help.
Faizan Roshan

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at our Migrate from CSV File to Magento extension on Magento marketplace. I think it might be helpful in your case.